# chrome extension, popup window's height

Tags: google-chrome-extension

It seems to me that the popup window's height has a limit of 489 pixels.
If I'm setting the body element of the popup to 600 pixels of height, then popup window gets a scroll bar (because the page inside becomes larger) but the popup window doesn't change its size.

Is it possible to make the popup window's height bigger then 489 pixels?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Set `height` in css for both `html` and `body` elements.

Comment: THANK YOU! you must add the `height` CSS attribute to the `HTML` element not just the `BODY`

Comment: Okay.. I'm sorry, but I can't seem to figure out how to get a reference to the `html` element.. ?

Comment: DOES NOT WORK on wondows

Comment: Those claiming it doesn't work: are you *sure* you're using the CSS approach?
e.g. `<html style="height: 300px;">` and `<body style="height: 300px;">`

Comment: It wasn't working for me either. I found that having padding on elements inside the body can break the height parameters.

Comment: Note that `rem` didn't work for me, I had to declare the number is `px` ie: `height: 400px;`.

Answer (score 6):

The popup window for chrome extensions has a maximum height and width. That is why the solution to set the height of body and html elements does work in some cases, and does not work in others. For Windows, the max height seems to be set to 489 pixels.

Additionally, the size of the popup does generally fit the size of its (relatively positioned) elements. This is also the case if the DOM of the popup is dynamically changed. So, setting the height for the popup window should usually not be nessecary.

Comment: It appears to me as though the maximum height is 600px. Maybe it varies by screen resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The popup should size to fit the (relatively positioned) content inside. Alternatively, you can set the `height` CSS property on the body of the your popup page to force it to a particular height.

You can also hide the scrollbar by setting `overflow: hidden;` on body.

Comment: It fits perfectly up to 489 pixels, if bigger than this number then it shows scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

If your popup is only for updating settings of your extension. The best way is to create a seprate setting page called `options_page`,not popup.

A reference about options_page is [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/options.html).

Comment: my extension is kind of tab manager, so it couldn't be option page.